# fail to install heroku on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, installation

I am trying to install heroku on ubuntu with 'wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh'. However, I get a Error which said that 'E: 未发现软件包(no Package found) heroku-toolbelt'!

W: 无法下载 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./en  不能连接到 toolbelt.heroku.com：http： [IP: 107.22.234.17 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
正在读取软件包列表... 完成
正在分析软件包的依赖关系树
正在读取状态信息... 完成
E: 未发现软件包 heroku-toolbelt
houxianxu@houxianxu-N80Vn:~$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site toolbelt.heroku.com is blocked in China, you should use a solution for GFW issues to access it like [this](http://ruby-china.org/topics/10813).