# Error installing Heroku Toolbelt: Unable to locate package heroku-toolbelt

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I encounter an error when installing Heroku Toolbelt. My OS is ubuntu-12.04. I found a similar problem in stackoverflow: [fail to install heroku on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262597/fail-to-install-heroku-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts). His error report is similar with mine and we are both from China. From that post, the cause and solution he said is "Site toolbelt.heroku.com is blocked in China, you should use a solution for GFW issues to access it like this." But I am not sure we have the same problem.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the installation and how to fix it? Thanks! My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. Below is my installing info:

```
administrator@ubuntu:~/mysite$ wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | LC_ALL=C sh
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
[sudo] password for administrator: 
--2013-10-17 10:56:27--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)... 54.243.76.97, 174.129.17.173, 23.21.198.2
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com (toolbelt.heroku.com)|54.243.76.97|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1737 (1.7K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

100%[======================================>] 1,737       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-10-17 10:56:29 (8.89 MB/s) - written to stdout [1737/1737]

OK
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                 
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                       
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                     
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                          
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                    
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                      
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                    
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                    
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                  
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources            
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources              
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources            
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages            
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages      
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages        
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages      
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex         
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex     
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources                
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources          
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources            
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources          
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages          
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages    
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages      
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages    
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex       
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex 
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex 
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                        
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en             
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en             
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en               
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en           
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en     
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en     
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en       
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en         
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                   
Err http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg                                  
  Connection failed [IP: 174.129.17.173 80]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources               
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en            
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Err http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages                          
  Connection failed [IP: 23.21.198.2 80]
Err http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en
  Connection failed [IP: 54.243.76.97 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Release.gpg  Connection failed [IP: 174.129.17.173 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./Packages  Connection failed [IP: 23.21.198.2 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/./en  Connection failed [IP: 54.243.76.97 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku-toolbelt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's totally GFW issue. Now I fix it. If you have the some problem with me, you can try my approach. In fact, cracking the great firewall is not so hard. The process took me a little more than 1 hour.

In short, my approach is installing goagent and then adding a configuration. The detail is:

1, installing goagent: https://code.google.com/p/goagent/wiki/InstallGuide

2, adding a config:

```
sudo su # you need root privilege first
echo "Acquire::http::Proxy \"http://127.0.0.1:8087\";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/40proxy
```

Note: after step 1, you can crack the great firewall (GFW), and after step 2, you can finally solve the heroku toolbelt installing problem as I encountered.

Thanks everyone who contributes to the solve of the problem!

Resource:

http://my.oschina.net/swuly302/blog/155971

https://code.google.com/p/goagent/wiki/InstallGuide

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this problem:

```
# Use the "https" instead of "http" for the heroku's sources.list
echo "deb https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list

#Install apt-transport-https in order to support https
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
```